# How do I use (probably) a temp table instead of all these SELECT statements inside my INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, refactoring, temp-tables

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertStuff]
    @RequestId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ([Id], [Column2], [AnotherColumn])
    VALUES
        ((SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE Id = @RequestId)
        ,(SELECT Column2 FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE Id = @RequestId)
        ,(SELECT AgreementTypeId FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE Id = @RequestId))
END
```

How can I modify it so I am not doing all these select statements... which is horrible for performance let along just terrible design. I am assuming I can use a temp table but I'd like to see it spelled out for me on where and how I would do this in a stored procedure. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable]
    ([Id]
    ,[Column2]
    ,[AnotherColumn])
SELECT Id, Column2, AgreementTypeId 
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE Id = @RequestId
```

Comment: is the VALUES keyword required?

Comment: @Bubbas Values keyword is needed when you're inserting a row from values given in the statement, with either values directly in the sql clause or variables, but using select clause is alternative for that. You can find different options from the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx#OtherTables

Comment: So if I did need to insert one value from a parameter as well as keep values from previous records I can do so with the SELECT.

    SELECT Id, Column2, @AgreementTypeId

Comment: @Bubbas Yes, you can use all the same things as in normal select clause

Answer (score 0):

Can't you say like

```
SELECT Id,Column2,AgreementTypeId  
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE Id = @RequestId
```